# Email management design

Tags: database, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to design a simple email management system for my application.

I get a problem managing the "Reply to" feature .
Declaring a mail message object and its to, cc, bcc list is simple , but when replying to the message , I need away to handle the relationship with all the messages which were replied on the original message .

id there any free system or datamodel doing this .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) that perhaps you can use. Every message has a collection of child messages (replies).

Check examples [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx#_self2) and [here](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html)